# Sorting list of strings based on a list of ints (Python)

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have two lists

```
X = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
Y = [3, 1, 5, 2]
```

and want to sort the list `X` to

```
X = ["c", "a", "d", "b"]
```

based on descending values of items in list `Y` in the corresponding positions

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Comment: why don't you use dictionary, or do you really need to have two different lists.

Comment: You have an `index out of range`. Index 5 has no correspond item in `X`.

Comment: There's actually even simpler way than the accepted answer:
`dict(zip(Y, X)).values()[::-1]`

Comment: @Martin - dicts are unordered by definition, and so are the sequences (views) returned by `values()`, `keys()` or `items()`, any kind of ordering you see is due to the used hashing implementation and as such an imlementation detail. Never rely on the ordering of a dict (unless of a special dict imlememtation like OrderedDict)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuples, by default, are ordered by the first value.

So zip the lists with `Y`'s items first, sort it (reversed) and then extract the second item (`X`):

```
>>> sorted_list = [item[1] for item in sorted(zip(Y, X), reverse=True)]
>>> sorted_list
['c', 'a', 'd', 'b']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to keep the mapping and then do the sort:

```
>>> X
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

>>> Y
[3, 1, 5, 2]

>>> d = dict(zip(X, Y))

>>> sorted(X, key=lambda x: d[x], reverse=True)
['c', 'a', 'd', 'b']
```

Comment: no problem... and just a small other hint: instead of a lambda you could use `key=d.get` (or `d.__getitem__`), but the general problem with this solution is that it does only work if there are no duplicate keys in `X`.

Comment: @mata thanks.. i have learned a few things :)

Answer (score 1):

```
X = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
Y = [3, 1, 5, 2]
zipped = zip(Y,X)
zipped.sort()
print zipped
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'a'), (5, 'c')]
```

Comment: Might be worth to mention that in python3 `zip` doesn't return a list but a zip object wich doesn't have a `.sort()` method. `sorted(zip(Y, X))` would work in both python2 and python3.